# Minify JS issue

Tags: magento2.2.4

If minify JS is enabled, when trying edit products give 21 URL errors.

> Refused to execute script from < URL > because its MIME type
>   ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is
>   enabled.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is cause the Klarna Module overrides xml node to exclude js from minifying. See issue https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/11577